# Differentiating $f(x)=\sin(2x) \ln(\sec x)$ for $-\pi/2 < x < \pi/2$

Tags: calculus

> Differentiate $f(x)=\sin(2x) \ln(\sec x)$ (with $-\pi/2 < x < \pi/2$).

Hello I was wondering if someone could help, I have found the derivate of $f(x)=\sin(2x)\ln(\sec x)$ but I am unsure if I need to do anything with the  ($-\pi/2 <x < \pi/2$) part of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only to ensure that $\sec x=\frac{1}{\cos x}$ is **defined**.

Note that $\cos(\pm\pi/2)=0$ and therefore $\sec x$ and $f(x)$ are not defined at $\pm \pi/2$.

So if you have calculated the derivative correctly using the chain rule, you should get

$$f^\prime(x)=2\sin(x)^2 + 2\cos(2x)\ln(\sec(x))$$

Comment: As has already been answered it's just to keep the function well defined. Please note that the answer to the differentiation given by TooOldForMath is WRONG though!

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin 2x\log\sec x=\sin 2x\log\frac1{\cos x}=\sin 2x(-\log\cos x)=-\sin 2x\log\cos x$$

Can you see now more clearly why the definition domain?

Now apply the chain rule and the product rule for differentiation:

$$(\log\cos x)'=-\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}=-\tan x\;,\;\;(\sin 2x)'=2\cos 2x\;\ldots$$

Comment: Perhaps you mean $(\sin 2x)' = 2 \cos 2x$

Comment: Yup @TanmayInamdar, thanks.